# скрыть блоки CSS

Tags: css

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto');
body{
    background-color: black;
}
.iphone{
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 250px;
  height: 500px;
  border-radius: 30px;
  background-color: #E9EAE4;
}

.camera{
  width: 15px;
  height: 15px;
  background-color: red;
  position: absolute;
  margin-left: 120px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  border-radius: 50px;
  background-color: #C5C3BA;
}
  .glass{
    height: 7px;
    width: 7px;
    margin: 4px;
    position: absolute;
    border-radius: 20px;
    background-color: #ABA99F;
}
.speaker{
  background-color: #C5C3BA;
  width: 60px;
  height: 15px;
  position: absolute;
  margin-top: 35px;
  margin-left: 95px;
  border-radius: 30px;
}
  .pre-speaker{
  width: 50px;
  height: 8px;
  background-color: #ABA99F;
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 30px;
  margin-top: 4px;
  margin-left: 5px;
}
.display{
  background-color: darkgray;
  width: 210px;
  height: 380px;
  margin-left: 20px;
  margin-top: 60px;
  position: absolute;
  border: 2px solid #ADABA1;
}
.display img{
  margin-top: 112px;
}
.button{
  background-color: #C5C3BA;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  position: absolute;
  margin-top: 445px;
  margin-left: 100px;
  border-radius: 100px;
}
  .snap{
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #E9EAE4;
    border-radius: 8px;
    width: 25px;
    height: 25px;
    margin-top: 13px;
    margin-left: 13px;
}
.onoff{
  background-color: #D9D7D0;
  width: 40px;
  height: 5px;
  margin-left: 170px;
  margin-top: -5px;
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 6px 6px 0px 0px;
}
.rocker{
  border-radius: 3px 0px 0px 3px;
  width: 5px;
  height: 25px;
  position: absolute;
  margin-top: 70px;
  margin-left: -5px;
  background-color: #D9D7D0;
}
  .two{
  margin-top: 110px;
}
  .three{
    margin-top: 150px;
}

.unlocker{
  margin: 0;
  background-image: url(http://2obl.ru/upload/2obl/information_system_19/3/7/2/item_3728/information_items_3728.jpg);
  opacity: 1;
  width: 211px;
  height: 380px;
  transition: 1s;
}
.time{
  position: absolute;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  margin-left: 90px;
  font-size: 60px;
  color: white;
}

.date{
  position: absolute;
  margin-top: 130px;
  margin-left: 60px;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  color: white;
}

#search{
  margin-top: 30px;
  position: absolute;
  margin-left: 5px;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 10px;
  border: 1px solid white;
  width: 200px;
}

.batary{
  position: absolute;
  width: 210px;
  height: 15px;
}

.MTS{
  position: absolute;
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  background-color: gray;
  border-radius: 10px;
  border: 1px solid white;
}

.one1{
  margin-left: 12px;
}

.two2{
  margin-left: 25px;
}
.three3{
  margin-left: 37px;
  background-color: darkgray;
}
.four4{
  margin-left: 49px;
  background-color: darkgray;
}
.five5{
  margin-left: 61px;
  background-color: darkgray;
}
.text_mts{
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  color: white;
  font-size: 12px;
  margin-left: 80px;
}
.display:hover .unlocker{
  height: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="body_two">
<div class="iphone">
  <div class="onoff"></div>
  <div class="rocker"></div>
  <div class="rocker two"></div>
  <div class="rocker three"></div>
  <div class="camera">
    <div class="glass"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="speaker">
    <div class="pre-speaker"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="display">
    <div class="batary">
      <div class="online">
       <div class="MTS one1"></div>
       <div class="MTS two2"></div>
       <div class="MTS three3"></div>
       <div class="MTS four4"></div>
       <div class="MTS five5"></div>
       <div class="MTS six6"></div>
       <div class="text_mts">MTS</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="unlocker" id='unlock'>
      <input type="text" name="" placeholder="Search" id="search" />
      <p class="time">4:20</p>
      <p class="date">Sunday, 11 february</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="button">
    <div class="snap"></div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

На стороннем редакторе: [codepen-ZLRPwd](http://codepen.io/Vaynshtein/pen/ZLRPwd)

Есть блок `.unlocker`, почему в свойствах я прописал, что бы скрывать его, а текст в нем остается? Или дополнительно прописать еще и для текста?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Что бы текст не вылезал, нужно добавить к стилю `overflow: hidden;`, а из за того, что у вас в дочерних элементах указана `position: absolute`, то для `.unlocker` нужно ещё добавить `position: relative;`, что бы он скрыл все блоки

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto');
body{
    background-color: black;
}
.iphone{
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 250px;
  height: 500px;
  border-radius: 30px;
  background-color: #E9EAE4;
}

.camera{
  width: 15px;
  height: 15px;
  background-color: red;
  position: absolute;
  margin-left: 120px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  border-radius: 50px;
  background-color: #C5C3BA;
}
  .glass{
    height: 7px;
    width: 7px;
    margin: 4px;
    position: absolute;
    border-radius: 20px;
    background-color: #ABA99F;
}
.speaker{
  background-color: #C5C3BA;
  width: 60px;
  height: 15px;
  position: absolute;
  margin-top: 35px;
  margin-left: 95px;
  border-radius: 30px;
}
  .pre-speaker{
  width: 50px;
  height: 8px;
  background-color: #ABA99F;
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 30px;
  margin-top: 4px;
  margin-left: 5px;
}
.display{
  background-color: darkgray;
  width: 210px;
  height: 380px;
  margin-left: 20px;
  margin-top: 60px;
  position: absolute;
  border: 2px solid #ADABA1;
}
.display img{
  margin-top: 112px;
}
.button{
  background-color: #C5C3BA;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  position: absolute;
  margin-top: 445px;
  margin-left: 100px;
  border-radius: 100px;
}
  .snap{
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #E9EAE4;
    border-radius: 8px;
    width: 25px;
    height: 25px;
    margin-top: 13px;
    margin-left: 13px;
}
.onoff{
  background-color: #D9D7D0;
  width: 40px;
  height: 5px;
  margin-left: 170px;
  margin-top: -5px;
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 6px 6px 0px 0px;
}
.rocker{
  border-radius: 3px 0px 0px 3px;
  width: 5px;
  height: 25px;
  position: absolute;
  margin-top: 70px;
  margin-left: -5px;
  background-color: #D9D7D0;
}
  .two{
  margin-top: 110px;
}
  .three{
    margin-top: 150px;
}

.unlocker{
  position: relative; /* Что бы текст не вылезал */
  margin: 0;
  background-image: url(http://2obl.ru/upload/2obl/information_system_19/3/7/2/item_3728/information_items_3728.jpg);
  opacity: 1;
  width: 211px;
  height: 380px;
  transition: 1s;
  overflow: hidden; /* Что бы текст не вылезал */
}
.time{
  position: absolute;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  margin-left: 90px;
  font-size: 60px;
  color: white;
}

.date{
  position: absolute;
  margin-top: 130px;
  margin-left: 60px;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  color: white;
}

#search{
  margin-top: 30px;
  position: absolute;
  margin-left: 5px;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 10px;
  border: 1px solid white;
  width: 200px;
}

.batary{
  position: absolute;
  width: 210px;
  height: 15px;
}

.MTS{
  position: absolute;
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  background-color: gray;
  border-radius: 10px;
  border: 1px solid white;
}

.one1{
  margin-left: 12px;
}

.two2{
  margin-left: 25px;
}
.three3{
  margin-left: 37px;
  background-color: darkgray;
}
.four4{
  margin-left: 49px;
  background-color: darkgray;
}
.five5{
  margin-left: 61px;
  background-color: darkgray;
}
.text_mts{
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  color: white;
  font-size: 12px;
  margin-left: 80px;
}
.display:hover .unlocker{
  height: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="body_two">
<div class="iphone">
  <div class="onoff"></div>
  <div class="rocker"></div>
  <div class="rocker two"></div>
  <div class="rocker three"></div>
  <div class="camera">
    <div class="glass"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="speaker">
    <div class="pre-speaker"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="display">
    <div class="batary">
      <div class="online">
       <div class="MTS one1"></div>
       <div class="MTS two2"></div>
       <div class="MTS three3"></div>
       <div class="MTS four4"></div>
       <div class="MTS five5"></div>
       <div class="MTS six6"></div>
       <div class="text_mts">MTS</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="unlocker" id='unlock'>
      <input type="text" name="" placeholder="Search" id="search" />
      <p class="time">4:20</p>
      <p class="date">Sunday, 11 february</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="button">
    <div class="snap"></div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```